# Keras CNN-RNN won't train. Could use some debugging

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I've got a binary classification problem I'm training where I am fairly successful at passing my data through a pre-trained embedding later, then few CNNs in parallel, pooling the results, and then using a dense layer to predict the class. But when I instead layer an RNN after the CNNs, the training completely fails. The code is below (this is a long post).

Here's the working CNN-only model. My input are vectors of length 100.

```
inputs=L.Input(shape=(100))
embedding=L.Embedding(input_dim=weights.shape[0],\
                          output_dim=weights.shape[1],\
                          input_length=100,\
                          weights=[weights],\
                          trainable=False)(inputs)
conv3 = L.Conv1D(m, kernel_size=(3))(dropout)
conv4 = L.Conv1D(m, kernel_size=(4))(dropout)
conv5 = L.Conv1D(m, kernel_size=(5))(dropout)
maxpool3 = L.MaxPool1D(pool_size=(100-3+1, ), strides=(1,))(conv3)
maxpool4 = L.MaxPool1D(pool_size=(100-4+1, ), strides=(1,))(conv4)
maxpool5 = L.MaxPool1D(pool_size=(100-5+1, ), strides=(1,))(conv5)
concatenated_tensor = L.Concatenate(axis=1)([maxpool3,maxpool4,maxpool5])
flattened = L.Flatten()(concatenated_tensor)
output = L.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(flattened)
```

and here's the summary:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_25 (InputLayer)            (None, 100)           0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_25 (Embedding)         (None, 100, 50)       451300      input_25[0][0]                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_25 (Dropout)             (None, 100, 50)       0           embedding_25[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_73 (Conv1D)               (None, 98, 100)       15100       dropout_25[0][0]                 
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_74 (Conv1D)               (None, 97, 100)       20100       dropout_25[0][0]                 
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_75 (Conv1D)               (None, 96, 100)       25100       dropout_25[0][0]                 
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_73 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 1, 100)        0           conv1d_73[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_74 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 1, 100)        0           conv1d_74[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_75 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 1, 100)        0           conv1d_75[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_25 (Concatenate)     (None, 3, 100)        0           max_pooling1d_73[0][0]           
                                                                   max_pooling1d_74[0][0]           
                                                                   max_pooling1d_75[0][0]           
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_25 (Flatten)             (None, 300)           0           concatenate_25[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_47 (Dense)                 (None, 1)             301         flatten_25[0][0]                 
====================================================================================================
```

As I said above, this works fairly well, getting good accuracy after just 3-4 epochs. However, my thought process is that the CNNs identify regional patterns, but if I want to also model how those relate to each other over longer distances in a given input vector, I should use some flavor of an RNN after the convolution. So I've tried changing the `pool_size` of the `MaxPooling1D` layers after convolution, removed the `Flatten`, and instead passing the `Concatenate` layer into an RNN. For example

```
maxpool3 = L.MaxPool1D(pool_size=((50,), strides=(1,))(conv3)
maxpool4 = L.MaxPool1D(pool_size=((50,), strides=(1,))(conv4)
maxpool5 = L.MaxPool1D(pool_size=(49,), strides=(1,))(conv5)
concatenated_tensor = L.Concatenate(axis=1)([maxpool3,maxpool4,maxpool5])
rnn=L.SimpleRNN(75)(concatenated_tensor) 
output = L.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(rnn)
```

And the summary now becomes:

```
max_pooling1d_95 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 50, 100)       0           conv1d_97[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_96 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 50, 100)       0           conv1d_98[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_97 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 49, 100)       0           conv1d_99[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_32 (Concatenate)     (None, 149, 100)      0           max_pooling1d_95[0][0]           
                                                                   max_pooling1d_96[0][0]           
                                                                   max_pooling1d_97[0][0]           
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
simple_rnn_5 (SimpleRNN)         (None, 75)            13200       concatenate_32[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_51 (Dense)                 (None, 1)             76          simple_rnn_5[0][0]               
====================================================================================================
```

When I train the model, the predictions are all exactly the same: the ratio of class[1] to class[0]. I've read a few papers where people have used this scheme successfully so obviously I'm doing something wrong, and I bet it is an embarrassingly silly mistake. Anyone care to help diagnose it?

Comment: Have you treid using an bidirectional LSTM without convolution? In general you don´t need these convolutional layers, if you use LSTMs. Anyway I think the problem in this case is that your recurrent layer is using the 149 axis as the sequence axis, is this what you want to do?
RNNS input: 3D tensor with shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim).

Comment: I have tried bidirectional RNNs of a few different flavors, with far worse success than this CNN scheme, believe it or not.Thanks for the tip on the RNN axis--I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you could try is to concatenate along the feature axis, not the time axis. 
Basically try this:

```
maxpool3 = L.MaxPool1D(pool_size=(50,), strides=(1,))(conv3)
maxpool4 = L.MaxPool1D(pool_size=(50,), strides=(1,))(conv4)
maxpool5 = L.MaxPool1D(pool_size=(50,), strides=(1,))(conv5)
concatenated_tensor = L.Concatenate(axis=2)([maxpool3,maxpool4,maxpool5])
rnn=L.SimpleRNN(75)(concatenated_tensor) 
output = L.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(rnn)
```

(Note that you have to make sure maxpool3, maxpool4, and maxpool5 would have the same number of "time" steps or maxpool3.shape[1]=maxpool4.shape[1]=maxpool5.shape[1])

Second, with 50 time steps, give LSTM or GRU a shot as they can capture longer time dependencies better than LSTM.

Comment: I think you meant "RNN" at the very end ("...better than LSTM"). However, I should also note that the `concatenated_tensor` doesn't go into the RNN as written. Error is: